# How to debug a "connection refused" error with tshark?

Tags: networking, wireshark, netcat, tshark

I'm trying to establish a simple TCP connection between two machines in the same subnet (wireless network). The tool used is **netcat**.

On machine A, I start a listener:

```
nc -l -p 4506
```

On machine B, I fire up the request:

```
nc -vv <machine_A_ip> 4506
```

While the output on machine A stays untouched, the output from netcat on machine B prints the following error:

```
<machine_A> [<machine_A_ip>] 4506 (?) : Connection refused
 sent 0, rcvd 0
```

Since machine B is headless, I have access only to **tshark** as a debugging tool. To debug this issue, I have tried to set the capture filter like this:

```
tshark -i wlan0 -f 'port 4506'
```

But tshark won't capture any packages. What am I missing? How do I properly debug the point of failure?

Comment: Ignoring tshark for the moment, two things to check: first, run `netstat -an | grep 4506` on machine A to make sure netcat is actually listening on that port. Certain versions of netcat want the port to be an argument to the `-l` option. Second, look at the iptables/firewall configuration on machine A to make sure port 4506 is not blocked.

Comment: @JeremyDover just checked that machine A is indeed listening in the 4506 port. Firewall is disabled in machine A. Gonna check machine B as well

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I was making a basic and bizarre mistake: I was swapping the IP addresses of both machines, so I was listening on machine A and making a request from machine B to machine B. Since this was using B's lo interface, I couldn't capture the packages in the wlan0 interface.

Oops! :)